# Slow Rails 2.2 performance on Linux vs OS X

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, macos, performance

I'm not sure if this is the right forum to post this as this is not a programming question.  But I just started working at a new company which is a Mac shop.  I use Linux Mint however and my page requests are rendering almost 2 times slower than on my colleagues' Macs.

**Macs**

```
Intel Core i7 @ 2.30GHz
16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M 2048 MB
OS X 10.9.2 (13C64)
Thin web server (v1.4.1 codename Chromeo)
```

**Linux**

```
Intel Core i7-4770 @ 3.40GHz
12GB 1600 MHz DDR3
Intel Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller 256MB
Linux Mint 16 (based on Ubuntu 13.10)
Thin web server (v1.4.1 codename Chromeo)
```

The bottleneck is in the rendering of views.  I'm using Mint's out of the box video driver.  Here are the times of rendering an example page.  This is basically the average performance.  My Linux machine is about 2x slower:

`Mac:` Completed in 1712ms (View: 667, DB: 105)

`Linux:` Completed in 3102ms (View: 1383, DB: 95)

Any other info I can provide?

Comment: Without code we cant possibly help you. Also Rails 2.2 is deprecated.

Comment: Are there any partials included in the view, and are there rendering times given broken down by partial? Anything else you can tell us about the view? Do you see this difference on all views, only big/complex views? Agreed Rails 2.2 is very old now. While not related to your question, this company might be able to help if you were using at least Rails 2.3: http://rubybackports.com/. (No I'm not affiliated with them in any way.)

Comment: @Senjai, all pages are rendering roughly 2x slower on Linux than on a Mac. Which code should I post?   I don't understand how posting code will help here.  Doesn't Mac Chrome render the same way as Linux Chrome?  Everyone's Mac is rendering 2x faster than my Linux machine.  The problem is not with the code, it's my Linux box.

Comment: You posted part of rails log (development.log?) and keep talking about graphic card and browser. You have ANY idea what you're talking about?

Comment: I'm sorry.  I have absolutely NO idea what I'm talking about.  That's why I'm posting here and asking for help.  Please help me understand how posting code will help in this question.

Comment: In this context, "render" isn't just rendering the graphics in your browser, it's processing your rails .erb file, running any ruby code you have in `<% %>` tags, interpolating variables, etc. While it's a bad idea, you could be making DB calls or calls to ebay.com from within your views that might add to the render time. Don't know why linux vs. mac would be that different; maybe heavy filesystem access? Is your linux machine swapping heavily or otherwise maxing its CPU, anything like that?

Comment: @sockmonk, I understand what you're saying about "render".  But as you can see in my post the DB calls are roughly equivalent on a Mac as on Linux (actually a bit faster on Linux).  I have 8 cores on my Linux box and 4 of them spike to 100% on and off for about 10s (the time of the page render).  There's no SWAP activity during this page request.